# Unable to locate config files when I tried to run chef-solo

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

When I ran ChefSolo in my server, it threw this error saying that it couldn't find my config file (solo.rb and nodes file), even though it is literally under my Chef directory.

```bsh
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j ".\nodes\test.json"
```

```
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] DEBUG: Reading products and relationships...
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] DEBUG: Successfully read products and relationships
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] DEBUG: Searching for the following licenses: ["infra-client", "inspec"]
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] DEBUG: Found license chef_infra_client at C:/Users/simon.lam/.chef/accepted_licenses/chef_in
fra_client
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] DEBUG: Found license inspec at C:/Users/simon.lam/.chef/accepted_licenses/inspec
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] DEBUG: Missing licenses remaining: []
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] DEBUG: All licenses present
[2019-06-24T07:04:56+00:00] FATAL: Cannot load configuration from .\nodes\local.json

PS C:\git\chef> chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 4.0.60
chef-client version: 15.0.300
delivery version: master (9d07501a3b347cc687c902319d23dc32dd5fa621)
berks version: 7.0.8
kitchen version: 2.2.5
inspec version: 4.3.2
```

when I specified the full path of solo.rb and node config file, it stops complaining

I have tried to installing Chef WorkStation and it still failed with the same error, couldnt find solo.rb. Just wondering if I have missed out any configuration to re-point chef to look into my own git chef directory (C:\git\chef... all my chef cookbooks, nodes and solo.rb are in here). But chef-solo keeps looking for solo.rb in C:\solo.rb, not sure why it does that (maybe the relative path is not working - potential bug).

Thanks

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell? i am confused ... [*blush*]

Comment: Created GitHub issue here https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/8714. thanks